# Find first N pentagonal numbers

Tags: java, methods, for-loop

I have to find the first `N [pentagonal numbers][1]` from 1-100 and display them 10 per line. I have to use the `getPentagonalNumber(int n)` method as well; that is obviously why it is there.

Here is my code so far.

```
package chapter_5;

public class Five_One {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0;
        int numPerLine = 10;
        for ( n = 0;  n < 11;  n ++)           
    }

    public static int getPentagonalNumber(int n) {
        int formula = n * (3 * n - 1) / 2;
        while ( formula < )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your >>concrete<< problem?

Comment: Mmmmm I really think I should not be helping you.... moral stuff. But I'll give you a hand so you can edit this code a bit. First, you have to print the number so you are missing a println somewhere. You also need anothe repetition structure like a for inside de while so print 10 numbers per line. Use print(number + " ") and when the counter reachs 10 use print(\n)

Comment: You will have to compute your formula for each values between 1 and n. To do this you will have to compute the formula inside the while. First tip I can give you: dont modify the value of a parameter, in other words avoid doing `n++` use an other variable to do the increment. Often `i`  variable is used inside a loop.

Answer (score 3):

This has a long way to go. Let's break it down here with a better approach.

Let's make a method that returns a set number of pentagonal numbers (we'll use an array.) This allows us to use the method later if perhaps there's extra credit too!

our signature looks like this:

```
class Jason {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // don't mix the calc routine and printing...
        int[] pents = getPentagonals(100); // calcs and stores the first 100 values

        final int numPerLine = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i < pents.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(pents[i]);
            System.out.print(" ");
            if(i % numPerLine == numPerLine - 1) System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    static int[] getPentagonals(int n) {
        int[] pents = new int[n];
        // calculate pents
        for(int i = 0; i < pents.length; i++) {
            // calculate the ith pentagonal here (assuming the 0th is first)
            // store it in pent[i]
        }
        return pents;
    }

}
```

Comment: `i % numPerLine = numPerLine - 1` Missing an `=`

Comment: @xanatos nice catch. Thankfully that's something that is caught by the ide, and failing there the compiler. Also, you have sufficient rep, you could edit it :-)

Comment: If I touch your code I'll need the gloves :-) I'm member of the `always use {}` sect and of the `no blank lines between } and } and no blank lines after {` support group. Practically another world :-) Still it's a +1 because it's good and correctly formatted, with lower case variables :-)

Comment: @xanatos fair enough. I'm of the camp that if it's short enough to fit on one line, then it's acceptable to do so. And I'm not a big fan of blank lines unless they're before or after class declarations. But that's just a matter of style, not a matter of whether or not it will compile. :-) (Heh that rhymes. Awesome.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, although i feel slightly retarded since i am still stumped! The issue i am having is somehow adding a numeric value for n, when i try n=0; then increment by one to execute the formula n*(3*n-1)/2 until n=10; i cannot because in the public static int getPentagonalNumber(int n) n is already assigned, i hope im even making sense

Comment: @Jason edit your post to give the latest version of the code and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: @Jason judging by the current version, here's what has to happen. 1) Take out everything AFTER the `int forumula = n * ...` line. Now you should have two lines there. All we want to do in this method is calculate a single value. 2) Add `return forumula` to the end of the method. This gets the formula back to the main program. 3) Put the call to `getPentagonalNumber(int)` inside a for loop or while loop. This lets you call the function however many times the loop executes.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are only executing the formula once and then incrementing it till you get 101. So you have essentionally done: 100 * (3 * 100 - 1) / 2 = 14950.

Consider having getPentagonalNumber return a single value and then call it x times with incrementing values starting at 1 until you get a value > 100 or until you have done it 100 times depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way I'd structure this is to have `getPentagonalNumber(int n)` return the `n`th pentagonal number--just calculating one at a time. That keeps it easy to understand and to test. Worry about compiling a list of them in the `main` function which can call your `getPentagonalNumber` function.

You may want to have your main function store results into a `List`. When the list `.size() == 10`, call `printResults(theResultList)` (which you'll write using some of the code currently in `main`) and `.clear()` the list. Especially when starting out, keeping functions small and responsibilities clearly separated will help you keep track of what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `return formula;` and not `return n;` since I assume you are trying to return the answer to your calculation?