# How to print 5 characters per line in Pencilcode?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

(Math: pentagonal numbers) A pentagonal number is defined as n(3n–1)/2 for n = 1, 2, . . ., and so on. Therefore, the first few numbers are 1, 5, 12, 22, . . . .

> Write a test program that uses this method to display the first 15 pentagonal numbers with 5 numbers on each line.

Here's what I've tried:

```
x = 0;
c = 1;
for (x=0; x < 3; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++, c++) {
    write(c*(3*c-1)/2);
  }
}
```

I was able to get it to print the Pentagonal numbers but every time it prints, it skips one line (so, it prints one number  per line). What I need is for it to print 5 number  per line in the total of 15 numbers. So, 3 lines).

P.S. The important thing is I have to do it in Pencil Code

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnqFG.png Here's the link to my code on the website

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find first N pentagonal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325410/find-first-n-pentagonal-numbers)

Comment: Is there a reason you've tagged this as Java?  I don't think Java programmers will be able to help you much.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Actually, there does appear to be something called PencilCode https://pencilcode.net/ ... but from what I can tell it supports javascript / coffeescript not java

Comment: @cricket_007 the language used by Pencil Code is actually Coffee Script.  It's not just plain pseudocode.

Comment: @Dan Ah. Does Coffeescript have static methods?

Comment: @cricket_007 This doesn't make sense as a pseudo-code question, because the complaint is about skipping lines, which depends on the exact semantics of `write`, which is language-specific.

Comment: pencilcode.net is a programming site that teaches you how to code on the web. After going to that website you can pick if you want it ti be javascript, HTML etc. The task is to use javascript option in pencil code.

Comment: @ajb Well, The code given isn't Java. It's closer to Javascript... Feel free to retag

Comment: And ... the requirements are talking about a method that **returns an int**.

Comment: I was given a hint to use "type()" or "typeline" method but I can't find anything about it

Comment: `public static int` isn't Javascript.  I'm voting to close this question as unclear because the language issue is confusing.

Comment: But it doesn't have the header that the instructions told you to write.  I'm still confused.

Comment: So that header was mentioned for JGrasp program. The task is to write in both JGrasp and pencilcode. I've managed the JGrasp so I only need pencilcode now. Deleted the header from task description. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0):

> Write a test program that uses this method

You're just calling some write method, not using that, so it's not really clear if the task is to learn methods, or write output, but here's how you can can format 5 numbers per line for 3 lines

```
n = 0;
for (var lines = 0; lines < 3; lines++) {
    line = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        line = line + getPentagonalNumber(n) + " ";
        n++;
    }
    write(line);
}
```

Comment: I suspect that instead of `getPentagonalNumber(n)`, you want `getPentagonalNumber(lines * 5 + n + 1)`.  Alternatively, you could make your inner loop `for (var n = lines * 5 + 1; n <= lines * 5 + 5; n++)`.

Comment: Oops, yeah. Though, it can be simpler by moving n to the outer scope

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PencilCode but I believe what you want is to type all responses from the inner `for` loop on the same line, and **then** move on to a new line after the inner loop finishes -- so in the end you'll have three lines of output.

I looked up PencilCode docs [here](https://gym.pencilcode.net/ref/type.html) and think what you want is to replace:

`write(c*(3*c-1)/2);`

with:

`type(c*(3*c-1)/2);`

and then add the following to add a space between each number:

`type " "`

Then add this after the inner `for` loop to move to a new line:

`typeline();`

So I think your final PencilCode would look something like this:

```
1    x = 0;
2    c = 1;
3    for (x=0; x < 3; x++) {
4        for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++, c++) {
5            type(c*(3*c-1)/2);
6            type " ";
7        }
8        typeline();
9    }
```

`type()` seems to just type on a line, but does not move the cursor to the next line -- it would be similar to `System.out.print()` in Java.

`typeline()` seems to type whatever is inside the parentheses, and then move the cursor to the next line. In this case, there is nothing, so all it does is just move the cursor to the next line -- it would be similar to `System.out.println()` in Java.

`Line 6` is to add a space between each number you will print out. I tried playing around in the docs [here](https://gym.pencilcode.net/ref/type.html), but it seemed like String concatenation does not work in PencilCode?

Anyways, I hope this solves your problem.